# i was trying to run the code and im still getting same error value error invalid file or buffer

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```py
import json 
import pandas as pd 
with open(r'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\vertpoal.com_vv.json')as d:
    dictData=json.load(d) 
df=pd.read_json(dictData)
```

and I'm getting error:

```
ValuErorr: invalid file path or buffer object type;<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictData)
```

Comment: i got another error if using all scalar values,you must pass an index

Comment: Could you please update your question by including `dictData`, or at least a sample of it.

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` transforms JSON to a python dict which is redundant, because `pd.read_json` expects '**a valid JSON str, path object or file-like object**'
(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

```
import pandas as pd 
with open(r'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\vertpoal.com_vv.json')as d:
    df=pd.read_json(d)
# some further actions with df object.
```

You should be able to access `df` variable outside of `with` scope.